# Collapsing resultset based on group by - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Input records in txn_ctry table:

```
txn_id  ben_code    ben_ctry    ben_score   orig_code   orig_ctry   orig_score
1       US          USA         1           ZZ          Unknown     -1
2       CA          Canada      1           PR          Portugal    2.3
2       DE          Germany     1.5         MX          Mexico      8.5
2       FR          France      2.5         ZZ          Unknown    -1
3       AA          Anon       -2           US          USA         1
3       CA          Canada      1           AA          Anon       -2
3       US          USA         1           AA          Anon       -2
```

Output Required:

```
txn_id  ben_code    ben_score   orig_code   orig_score
1       US          1           ZZ          -1
2       FR          2.5         MX           8.5
3       CA          1           US           1
```

Requirement is to find the highest ben_score and orig_score per txn_id as shown in the output.

As shown in the sample input data (more rows per txn_id can exist,but this is just a data snippet), txn_id = 1 has only one row and hence its straight forward.

Txn_id = 2 has 3 rows and the highest ben_score is for ben_code = FR and the highest orig_score is for orig_code = MX

In case of a tie between the codes within txnid, then the code with the ascending alphabetical order needs to be selected as is the case with txn_id = 3 where ben_code values of US and CA have a tie with the same high score of 1, but CA should be picked based on alphabetical order of the corresponding ctry column (ben_ctry and orig_ctry).

I would appreciate some solutions to get the desired output in a single query.

Answer (score 0):

This query will implement your requirements:

```
with enhanced_data as (
  select 
    data.txn_id,
    first_value(ben_code  ) over (
      partition by txn_id order by ben_score  desc, ben_code  asc) first_ben_code,
    first_value(ben_score ) over (
      partition by txn_id order by ben_score  desc, ben_code  asc) first_ben_score,
    first_value(orig_code ) over (
      partition by txn_id order by orig_score desc, orig_code asc) first_orig_code,
    first_value(orig_score) over (
      partition by txn_id order by orig_score desc, orig_code asc) first_orig_score
  from
    data
)
select distinct
  txn_id,
  first_ben_code,
  first_ben_score,
  first_orig_code,
  first_orig_score
from enhanced_data
order by txn_id
```

[See a SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/70d5a/4).

I suspect that you'll need proper indexing, if these are large data sets.